# How to make a random crossword puzzle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a task to create a randomize crossword puzzle 10x10 or 12x12, and I am wondering how do I start. Lets say I want grab a number of words from MySQL 2008  database. Example: dogs, cats.

I have created the table but I just need to know how to customize the code by using css in cshtml any help?

I have a  `<table id="crossword" >`

How do I input this set of  CSS codes in razor cshtml?

```
#crossword {
    color: #444;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4XV3z/4/

Comment: Please add more detail. It's not clear where/what the problem is. CSS doesn't really have much to do about creating a random crossword puzzle.

Comment: oh the problem is i just start create the crossword puzzle gui, by using tables but i trying to implment the color and the font size but it doesn't allow me to do so. so the problem is do i need a script or something to enable the #crossword function?

Comment: oh here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4XV3z/ , currently i trying to create a gui of the crossword puzzle first. but i having some problems setting up the lines and the borders etc.. hope someone can help

Comment: ops sorry is this set , i have placed at the wrong area.. http://jsfiddle.net/4XV3z/4/

Comment: yeah but in mvc4  how am i suppose to put the css codes into cshtml ? currently my tables are working but not the css..

Comment: You typically don't. You include the style sheet in the `head` of the _layout.cshtml like you would any other style sheet.

Comment: so how to i enable the css in my this current .cshtml?? i abit confused here lol

Comment: You add the class to the `td`. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/4XV3z/6/).

Comment: erm so where should i paste the css codes?? in the current cshtml? but it doesnt seems to work

Comment: You put the css code in a stylesheet like `crossword.css` and then reference this in the `head` of your _Layout.cshtml like `<link href="/content/crossword.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`... I think you could probably benefit from [some tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc) before attempting this project.

Comment: is there any useful link ? well  thanks alot the gui had been created. but i currently have to take some words from sql database how i suppose to do that in the controller? :D